Can I increase the field of view of a lens+camera system by placing a meniscus lens in front of it?
Let's say I have a camera + lens system. The lens is a standard focal length, let's say 25 mm on a 1/2" sensor, so not wide angle. Instead of mounting a wide angle lens on the camera, would it be possible to increase the field of view of the system by placing a meniscus lens between the scene and the camera?
I read that meniscus lenses are the key element in wide angle lens, to gather rather light rays at high angles.
The Thorlabs website says

When used in combination with another lens, a positive meniscus lens
will shorten the focal length and increase the numerical aperture (NA)
of the system without introducing significant spherical aberration

I did some tests by using rendering softwares (VRED/Blender). I loaded in the software the 3D model of a positive meniscus lens with the correct index of refraction (e.g. a Thorlabs N-BK7 150 mm positive meniscus lens with 2" diameter). I placed it in front of some objects and looked at the objects through the lens. However, I only see a magnification effect, so the field of view appears to be decreasing instead of increasing.
So what am I doing wrong? Is what I'm saying even possible with a lens/group of lenses? Can I widen the field of view of a camera+lens system by placing some sort of lens in front of it?

There are accessory lenses that do just this. Don’t expect image quality to be great. Google “wide angle accessory lens”

Thanks! I found it also by tiping "Wide-angle teleconverter"
